# Javascript map through array to make another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I want to go through an array of strings, and depending on what the string is, make an array of objects.

For example, if the array is:

```
[a,a,a,b,b,c,d]
```

I want to map through the array and make an object with key and value pairs that add up the strings consecutively:

```
[{a:1},{a:2},{a:3},{b:1},{b:2},{c:1},{d:1}]
```

How do I do this?

I've tried mapping through, but I can't get how to add on to the previous object's value (a:1 -> a:2)

Answer (score 3):

While mapping, you need to store a separate count of how many times each item has appeared, and increment the appropriate key each iteration. You might use a `Map` for this:

```js
const input = ['a','a','a','b','b','c','d'];
const map = new Map();
console.log(
  input.map(char => {
    const count = (map.get(char) || 0) + 1;
    map.set(char, count);
    return { [char]: count };
  })
)
```

Comment: ahh, that makes sense. Thanks!!

Comment: anyway can you help me understand how the map.get(char || 0) works?

Comment: @DiegoFlores note the position of the closing parens - it's `map.get(char) || 0`, which means get either the defined value for that char, or if the value was undefined (or othereise "falsey") replace it with a real zero, so that the subsequent `+ 1` will work.  `undefined + 1` isn't legal.

Comment: @DiegoFlores The `map` starts out empty. The first time a key is encountered (like the `a` on the first iteration), `map.get(char)` will return `undefined`, which isn't a number that can be added to. So, `map.get(char) || 0` is a quick way of getting an expression that evaluates to 0 if the key does not exist in the `map` yet. If the key *does* exist in the `map` already, then the expression evalutes to that (numeric) count.

Comment: ahh, I see! and then map.set updates the key/value pair of map, which can then be used for the next char in the array?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea